# Excel 2007, pivot table: how to do a running % of total?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, pivot, pivot-table

I have a pivot table, and ideally I want a running % of total...I am not sure how to do this without further processing my data (which I'd like to avoid). I can get a running total, but I can't have it divide by the ultimate value.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For percentage of total, Add the column to the values section.  Then go to "show values as" then select % of total.

How about you do running total beside % of total...

If you don't want to manipulate your data further, this is your best option in my opinion.

[image]